# Problems calling function with web3 from python

Tags: solidity, ether, ropsten, web3.py, python

I was trying to call a function from my python server to a contract deployed in Ropsten.

This is my method in the contract:

```
function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    emit Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
}
```

Here I try to call the method:

```
def default_reward():
    name =  request.json["ckan_user_id"]
    user = db["userinfos"].find_one({"ckan_user_id":name})
    address = user["bc_user_address"]
    contract = wb3.eth.contract(
                        address=config.audacoin_contract_address,
                        abi=get_abi_audacoin(),
                    )
    tx_hash = contract.functions.send(address, 5).call().transact({"from": config.ADMIN_ADDRESS})
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

    return "Sended"
```

But I can't call the function. ¿Anybody know how can I call this method?

Thanks very much.

**UPDATE**
I have changed the method, but I have a new error:

```
def default_reward():
    name =  request.json["ckan_user_id"]
    user = db["userinfos"].find_one({"ckan_user_id":name})
    address = user["bc_user_address"]
    contract = wb3.eth.contract(
                        address=config.audacoin_contract_address,
                        abi=get_abi_audacoin(),
                    )
    tx_hash = contract.functions.send(address, 5).transact({"from": config.ADMIN_ADDRESS})
    tx_receipt = wb3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
    return "Sended"
```

But I am having this error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 12:44:18] "POST /dataset/audacoin/default_reward HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/api/dataset.py", line 665, in default_reward
    tx_hash = contract.functions.send(address, 5).transact({"from": config.ADMIN_ADDRESS})
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1151, in transact
    **self.kwargs
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1454, in transact_with_contract_function
    txn_hash = web3.eth.sendTransaction(transact_transaction)
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 269, in sendTransaction
    [transaction],
  File "/home/ibai/Documentos/proyecto/AudablokAPI/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 112, in request_blocking
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

The issue is in the line where you try to transact with the function. You should not be invoking `call()` before `transact()`. The following modification should fix it:

```py
tx_hash = contract.functions.send(address, 5).transact({"from": config.ADMIN_ADDRESS})
```

#### Explanation

Given the wording of your question I think you maybe be unclear on [the difference between calling a contract and sending a transaction to a contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call):

- A **call** is a local invocation of a contract function that does not broadcast or publish anything on the blockchain. It is a read-only operation and will not consume any Ether. It simulates what would happen in a transaction, but discards all the state changes when it is done.
- A **transaction** is broadcasted to the network, processed by miners, and if valid, is published on the blockchain. It is a write-operation that will affect other accounts, update the state of the blockchain, and consume Ether (unless a miner accepts it with a gas price of zero).

The `web3.py` [contract API](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#contract-functions) allows you to call or transact with any contract function. `call` returns whatever value(s) the contract function returns, `transact` returns a transaction hash.

In your example you are first using `call()` to call the `send` function, which returns `None` because `send` has no return value. You are then attempting to call `transact` upon the returned `NoneType`, which raises an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Thanks very much, but it does not solve the problem at all, I have update the question with an error ocurred by this way.

Comment: Your new issue is that the node you are using (Infura?) does not have any unlocked accounts. You must sign the transaction locally and broadcast with `eth.sendRawTransaction`. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33231/how-to-build-a-raw-transaction-to-interact-with-a-contract-with-web3-py and https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-contract-transaction for info on how to do this.